# Flutter inject variable into profile and debug AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, manifest, inject

I am currently injecting variable values into ./android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml from build.gradle

```
    defaultConfig {
      ...
      manifestPlaceholders = [
            ...
            appPackageName: tenant.appPackageName,
      ]
    }
```

I would like to be able to inject the same value into the two built in manifest files in the profile and debug folders respectively, such as

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="${appPackageName}"> <-- THIS HERE
  <!-- Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
     to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
  -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

But I don't seem to be able to figure it out.
I am sure there must be a way to do that from build.gradle, but not sure where exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question:

- created a bash script that takes a .json configuration file and a template and creates config file in the root of the project. The result is something like

```
appPackageName=my.project.example
```

- created a gradle file that exposes the value of those variables

```
class TenantProperties {
    def appPackageName

    TenantProperties(Properties tenantProperties) {
        this.appPackageName = tenantProperties.getProperty('appPackageName')
    }
}

def tenantProperties = new Properties()
def tenantPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('tenant.properties')
if (tenantPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    tenantPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        tenantProperties.load(reader)
    }
}
ext {
    tenant = new TenantProperties(tenantProperties)
}
```

- the value of appPackageName is now available in build.gradle. What worked for me is to change "namespace" dynamically, depending on the value of appPackageName

```
android {
  ...
  namespace tenant.appPackageName
  ...
}
```

- all my AndroidManifest.xml can now consume that value as "package"

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="${appPackageName}"> <-- NO PROBLEM HERE!
    <!-- Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```